# How to implement a next button in flask?

Tags: python, flask, pagination

I am trying to use Flask to implement a basic query over a database. Each page should show up to 8 results, and if there are more than 8, it should have a next page button. Everything is working as intended except for the next page button, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the Python code I have:

```
@app.route("/results", methods=["POST"])
def results(result = None):
    """
    result page
    :return:
    """
    query_text = request.form["query"]  # Get the raw user query from home page
    #~results processing code removed as it's not relevant
    hasnext = False
    if len(r)>1:
        hasnext=True

    return render_template("results.html", query=query_text, hits=h , result=r[0], page=1, start = 1, hasnext = hasnext)  # add variables as you wish


@app.route("/results/<int:page_id>", methods=["POST"])
def next_page(page_id):
    """
    "next page" to show more results
    :param page_id:
    :return:
    """
    s = (page_id-1)*8+1  #numbering of results
    next = False
    if len(r) >= page_id:
        next = True
    return render_template("results.html", query=query_text, hits=h, result=r[page_id-1], page=page_id, start = s, hasnext = next)
```

and then here are the two ways I tried to implement the HTML I have for the button that isn't working:
This one doesn't work (even if I change the variable {{page_id}} to hard code a number)

```
<a href="{{ url_for('next_page', page_id={{page_id}}+1)}} ">Next
    <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
    <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
</a>
```

This one shows the button, and when I tried this code, I also added more to the Python:
Button:

```
{% if hasnext %}
<form method ="POST" action="/">
<input type="submit" name="Next" value="Next"/>
{%  endif %}
</form>
```

added to Python:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.form.get('Next') == 'Next':
                return render_template("results.html"...)
```

Any advice on how to implement the next button would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with [pagination](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate) within [flask sqlalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/)? [This](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ix-pagination) is a small tutorial on this. I think this way you could make your work easier.

Answer (score -1):

It's an old post but let me give it a shot. Have you tried to paginate your results? Try this in your python file.

```
@app.route("/results")
def results():
page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
query_text = Text.query.paginate(page=page,per_page=5)
return render_template('result.html', query_text =query_text)
```

Then at your results.html insert this code before {% endblock content %} :

```html
{% for page_num in query_text.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}
      {% if page_num %}
        {% if query_text.page == page_num %}
          <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('results', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
        {% else %}
          <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('results', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
        {% endif %}
      {% else %}
        ...
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```