# Showing demo step by step with flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to show a demo of a function I wrote in Python, using Flask. I have a list of examples of different inputs and outputs, assigned to a variable.
So I want to iterate thru the list, and display each example by itself in a single page. The user is prompted if he wants to see a detailed explanation of how the answer was obtained. And there are two buttons, let's call them "Yes" and "No".
If "yes" is pressed, then some extra info is displayed. At the end, there should be a "Next" button, that does the same as "no" (described below)
If "no" then I want to go on to the next example in the list.

How is this done?

In my *.py file:

```
@app.route('/demo', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def demo():
   examples = [[first example stuff],[second...], ... ]
   for index in range(0, len(examples)):
        example = examples[index]
        if 'yes' in request.form:
           return render_template('demo.html', example=example, answer=True)
        elif 'no' in request.form:
           pass  # Continue with demo
        return render_template('demo.html', example=example, answer=False)
```

And in my demo.html template:

```
   {{ example }}

   <p>Do you want to see how the answer was reached?</p>
   <form method = "post">
      <input type = "submit" name = "yes" value = "Sure!">
      <input type = "submit" name = "no"  value = "No, thanks">
   </form>

   {% if answer %}
      <!--show extra info -->
   (% endif %}
```

*This is not working*, and I just don't know how to do it.
I have looked at these links, but could not figure out what to do:

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+add+next+button+in+flask

[How to implement a next button in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66360199/how-to-implement-a-next-button-in-flask)

Thanks!

Comment: using `for`-loop is totally wrong idea. When you press buttom then it runs again `demo()` so it starts again `for`-loop which get only first example. You button should send number of current example and `demo()` should use this number to get data for correct example

Comment: simply use `print()` in `demo()` to display values in variables and you will see that it is wrong idea.

Comment: maybe instead of `<form>` use normal `<a>` with links like `/demo/1` `demo/2` or even `/demo/1/yes` `demo/2/no` - or in `<form>` add field with demo number

Comment: your `elif ...: pass` is useless - you can remove it and code will work the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up doing it.

In my python file:

```
index :int
# I decided to put the steps as a global list, so that it doesn't assign it to the variable
# each time that demo() and step_by_step() are called, and so that I don't need to pass as argument
demo_steps = [...]

# demo just calls step_by_step(), but it always starts from 0
# So when user clicks on "demo" in navigator link, the demo restarts
@app.route('/demo')
def demo():
    global index
    index = 0
    return redirect(url_for('step_by_step', step=index))
    step_by_step(index)

@app.route('/demo/<int:step>', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def step_by_step(step):
    global index, demo_steps
    index = min(step, len(demo_steps)-1)  # to prevent a user from typing "/demo/20" (for example) in the URL
    short_answer = demo_steps[index][0]
    detailed_answer = demo_steps[index][1]

    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'yes' in request.form:
            return render_template('demo.html',
                                   short = short_answer,
                                   detailed = detailed_answer,
                                   show_answer = True)
        # user clicked 'no' ( = doesn't want detailed explanation),
        # or 'next' (after seeing the detailed explanation)
        # Either way, we move to the next step in the demo
        elif 'no' or 'next' in request.form:
            index += 1
            if index < len(demo_steps):
                return redirect(url_for('step_by_step', step=index))
                step_by_step(index)
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('finished'))
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('demo.html',
                   short = short_answer,
                   detailed = detailed_answer,
                   show_answer = False)

@app.route('/finished')
def finished():
    return render_template('finished.html') # A simple page saying demo is finished
```

And in my demo.html template:

```
<h1>The short answer is: {{ short }}</h1>

<p>Do you want to see how the answer was reached?</p>
<form method = "post">
    <input type = "submit" name = "yes" value = "Sure!">
    <input type = "submit" name = "no"  value = "No, thanks">
</form>

{% if show_answer %}
    <h3>These are the steps that the program took to find the answer</h3>
    {% for step in detailed %}
        <li>{{ step }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    <p></p>
    <form method = "post">
        <input type = "submit" name = "next" value = "Continue">
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for`-loop is totally wrong idea.

When you press button then it runs `demo` from the beginning and it runs `for`-loop again from the beginning so it always get first example.

You should put example number in `form` as hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="number" value="{{ example_number }}"/>
```

and get it from `form` when you press button

```
def demo():

    number = request.form.get('number', 0) # as default it will use `0`
    number = int(number)

    button = request.form.get('btn')
```

and first you can use `number` with buttons `next`, `previous` to change it

```
    if button == 'NEXT':
        if number < len(examples)-1:
            number += 1

    if button == 'PREV':
        if number > 0:
            number -= 1
```

and later you can use `number` to get correct example from list

```
    text = examples[number][0]
    if button == 'YES':
        help = examples[number][1]
    else:
        help = None
```

---

Minimal working example.

I use two forms to make it more readable.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

examples = [("Hello", "It is first help"), ("World", "It is second help")]

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    
    number = request.form.get('number', 0) # as default it will use `0`
    number = int(number)
    
    button = request.form.get('btn')

    print('number before:', number)
    
    if button == 'NEXT':
        if number < len(examples)-1:
            number += 1

    if button == 'PREV':
        if number > 0:
            number -= 1
            
    text = examples[number][0]
    if button == 'YES':
        help = examples[number][1]
    else:
        help = None
    
    print('number after :', number)
    print('text:', text)
    print('help:', help)
    
    return render_template_string('''
Text: {{ text }}
{% if help %}<br>Help: {{ help }} {% endif %}

<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="number" value="{{ example_number }}"/>
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="YES">YES</button>
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="NO">NO</button>
</form>

<!-- other elements  -->

<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="number" value="{{ example_number }}"/>
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="PREV">PREV</button>
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="NEXT">NEXT</button>
</form>
''', example_number=number, text=text, help=help)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value are yes and no thanks, so we can remove unneccessary things.

```
  <input type = "submit" name = "yes" value = "Sure!">
  <input type = "submit" name = "no"  value = "No, thanks"


@app.route('/demo', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def demo():
   examples = [[first example stuff],[second...], ... ]
   for example in examples:
        if request.form.get('yes') is not None:
           return render_template('demo.html', example=example, answer=True)
        elif request.form.get('no') is not None:
           pass  
        return render_template('demo.html', example=example, answer=False)
```